# Pruning Nodes in data.tree R

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, pruning

I have a decision tree stored as follows(using data.tree)(in R) :

Sex
  ¦--Male
  ¦   °--Class
  ¦       ¦--3rd
  ¦       ¦   °--Age
  ¦       ¦       ¦--Child
  ¦       ¦       ¦   °--No 
  ¦       ¦       °--Adult
  ¦       ¦           °--No 
  ¦       ¦--1st
  ¦       ¦   °--Age
  ¦       ¦       ¦--Adult
  ¦       ¦       ¦   °--No 
  ¦       ¦       °--Child
  ¦       ¦           °--Yes
  ¦       ¦--2nd
  ¦       ¦   °--Age
  ¦       ¦       ¦--Adult
  ¦       ¦       ¦   °--No 
  ¦       ¦       °--Child
  ¦       ¦           °--Yes
  ¦       °--Crew
  ¦           °--Age
  ¦               °--Adult
  ¦                   °--No 
  °--Female
      °--Class
          ¦--3rd
          ¦   °--Age
          ¦       ¦--Child
          ¦       ¦   °--No 
          ¦       °--Adult
          ¦           °--No 
          ¦--1st
          ¦   °--Age
          ¦       ¦--Adult
          ¦       ¦   °--Yes
          ¦       °--Child
          ¦           °--Yes
          ¦--2nd
          ¦   °--Age
          ¦       ¦--Adult
          ¦       ¦   °--Yes
          ¦       °--Child
          ¦           °--Yes
          °--Crew
              °--Age
                  °--Adult
                      °--Yes

This tree is stored in a variable : root
I want to prune the tree(calculate the chi-square values for all nodes with level = 6 and if their chi-square values are less than a threshold(example 6), then delete that node from the tree).

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm using the following dataset :
"","Class","Sex","Age","Survived"
"1","1st","Male","Child","No"
"2","2nd","Male","Child","No"
"3","3rd","Male","Child","No"
.
.
.

Using This, I use ID3 algorithm to create a decision tree. Now, I wanted to prune it.[image]

Comment: Use `Do` to walk the tree and calculate chi-square. Then use `Prune` directly. The representation of the tree is somewhat distorted. Pls use dput for your data.

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you provide a reproducible example

Comment: @Hack-R Please see edit.

Comment: @SiddharthSharma Thanks, that helps. For the R tag the way they generally like you to provide a reproducible example is to `dput()` the data then supply all code and library statements necessary to reproduce the error or problem. For more details check out the R tag description and this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve